# Can I do a repeated measures logistic regression for 16 students who answered different questions on a test?

Tags: regression, logistic, repeated-measures, item-response-theory

I had 15 students take a vocabulary test with 100 items at the end of a course and were scored "1" (correct) or "0" (incorrect) for each item. I would like to predict the likelihood of them getting a specific word correct based on how frequently they encountered the word during the course (input frequency) and how often they used the word in their assignments (productive use). Here is an example of what my data looks like:

```
student   word    input.freq  productive.use  score
1         影響     4           1               1
1         含まれる 10           0               1
1         燃える   4            0               0
2         影響     4           1               1
2         含まれる 10           0               0
2         燃える   4           2               1
```

Obviously I don't have a large sample size, so I was wondering if I could use repeated measures in order to do a logistical regression? However, I worry it may be problematic because they are being given different vocabulary words. If logistic regression cannot be used, are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, there is a specialization of this approach you should use. Item Response Theory (IRT) is the preferred approach to evaluating the operating characteristics of a test. The "2PL" approach uses a logistic probability curve for the likelihood of correct response and random slopes and intercepts for each question. It is essentially a latent variable modeling approach. The latent variable estimates assess the difficulty and discriminability (intercept and slope respectively) for each question, additionally, the "ability" of each student can be assessed by translating the score a latent probability. The overall reliability of the test can be assessed. And the empirical model can be tested against a null model where the slopes and intercepts are identical for each question: that is it assesses the adequacy of the total score for evaluating performance..

Comment: This is true, but perhaps you should extend your answer a bit. The OP asked if s/he could predict the probability of getting an answer correct depending on exposure to the word (i.e. input freq in the table). That would be an *explanatory* IRT model with exposure as a continuous predictor. A straight up IRT model would only get you the person's latent ability (verbal fluency, most likely). Naturally, you could then take this ability and run a regular regression, but it would probably under-estimate the uncertainty in verbal fluency - recall that in IRT you predict each person's mean *and SE*.

Comment: Yes, I am not interested in measuring student ability, item discriminability, or test reliability. I would like to see if I can predict the probability of a student getting an answer correct based on their prior interaction with the word (input frequency and productive use). However, I'm not sure if it is okay to do repeated measures with different vocabulary words.